# Blocking single webpage of a website

Tags: browser, search, browser-addons, blocking, hosts-file

I want to block google homepage, but want search result by typing keyword in browser's search bar.

I tried extension and host file approach, but it will make all of google in-accessible.

So I don't want to see "https://www.google.com" but want to access "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=alphabet&safe=strict" its the search result for word **alphabet** in Firefox with safe search on.

Comment: You would likely need to set up forwarding HTTP proxy (such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)) to inspect all your outgoing traffic, then use that proxy allow/block specific URLs. You can't do this through the `hosts` file at all and (as far as I am aware) it's doubtful a browser extension could do this.

Comment: If you just want to block *parts* of the Google home page, such as the *I'm Feeling Luck* button, Java script and graphic elements, uBlock Origin lets you make an appropriate rule, which can be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome On startup options are only:

> - Open the New Tab page
> - Continue where you left off
> - Open a specific page or set of pages

You can't open up Chrome without any page. Moreover, closing the last page
will close up Chrome.

The most you can do is to select the option of
"Open a specific page or set of pages" and choose a neutral page,
either from the internet, or even a local HTML file.